# Paypal Adaptive payment implementation on live environment

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

We have implemented Adaptive payment method. This implementation is working fine on `sandbox` environment. But its showing the following response in `Live` environment. We are not clear with the response. Can please provide the details about this response.

Response:

```
{
Array
(["en" class
[send_method] => domestic;icon-uri
[content_ID] => marketing_us/request_money;icon-uri
[amp;from] => PayPal">Sign Up
2" width [label] => xuVFCJezswQQmbe91QM [guid] => ON [script] => 0"/>
escalateTab">Contact
[ ($("#mobile_number").val() !] => ''))
    { 
        validPhoneNumber 
        [page] => main%3Amktg%3Apersonal%3A%3Ahome%3A%3A%3A 
        [tmpl] => core2HomeCExp.jsp
        [pgst] => Unknown 
        [lgin] => out 
        [calc] => f91c2b0c39598 
        [rsta] => en_US 
        [md5h] => 7fbf0dfca87f30b51dc1d9cb8dae4318 
        [shfp] => %7C%7C 
        [usce] => + [pgtf] => Sparta [s] => ci [aver] => unverified [rstr] => unrestricted [pfid] => f91c2b0c39598 
        [bzsr] => main [bchn] => mktg [pgsf] => personal [ccpg] => usa [pgld] => Unknown [shir] => main_mktg_personal_" alt [pgrp] => main%3Amktg%3Apersonal%3A%3Ahome )
}
```

Comment: What endpoint are you hitting?